# virt-manager process continues running after closing all of its windows, what should I do?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, process, virt-manager

I have installed `qemu`, `kvm`, and `virt-manager`, though I have noticed that after closing all of the `virt-manager` windows that there is still a `virt-manager` process running which originally appeared to be transitioning between the two states of `Running` and `Sleeping` very quickly and all of the time, but now it seems to have quietened down a bit though (it is now mostly on `Running` but from time to time changes to `Sleeping` for a few seconds) it is using over 150 MiB of RAM, but no CPU.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20, is it safe for me to end the process or is there some reason for it still to be running? Or a proper way for me to exit it rather than just closing all of its windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the process continues running is because when you close all of its windows it actually just minimizes to the tray, or at least, it carries on running until you have closed it using the `Quit` option either by choosing that for the option from the tray, or from `File > Quit` in one of the windows:

[image: Tray Quit Button]

[image: Window Quit Button]

As you probably will have also noticed from the last screenshot, you can also close it completely with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (though of course not when you're in a Virtual Session, otherwise the keyboard shortcut will just go to the VM rather than to `virt-manager`, or at least, `virt-manager` will think you're talking to the VM and give it to the VM rather than act upon the instructions itself.

So quitting the program in these ways should also get rid of the process so no need to end it manually (and probably a bad idea to just in case).